# Places Details - Google API for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm trying to develop a very simple Android Application that just tries to imitate some of the built-in Maps application of most Android phones. My goal is

1.) To embed the Google Map on my application (done already)

and

2.) To show the details of the place(landmark) whenever the user hovers over and clicks the marker of the place

I hope I am making sense here. I mean, I've tried to search here in stackoverflow.com if there are questions related to this but as far as I have researched, I did not find any. Please help me

Comment: Check your JSON data. Google places api send places with all the details associated with it.

Comment: @user-Kunu I'm sorry I didn't quite get you. can you explain further please?

Comment: Which api you are using for google maps?

Comment: I think this is the solution to my problem but I just don't know how to apply this. Do you have an idea? https://developers.google.com/places/android/place-details#get-place

Comment: What are you doing? 
What's exact problem?  
Where are you getting it? Nothing is clear from your question. It's really hard to understand what you want from your question. Show your code and more details

Comment: And that link is all about getting a place from placeId. If you have placeId then use that method to get place details

Comment: Okay so my situation is like this:

1. Using Android Studio, I created a Google Maps Activity.
2. To be able to use the API, we need a google maps key and I've already got one so I was able to use the map.
3. When I run the program, it runs perfectly.
4. However, for example I zoom into a landmark, say, "Cebu Plaza Independencia", and then I click it, nothing happens.
5. I want it to act like how the built-in Maps activity does - like there's a Red Marker that pops out and then when you click the marker, it will display information about the place. This is the problem

Comment: Refer [http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) and [http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-infowindow-contents-in-google-map-android-api-v2-using-infowindowadapter/](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-infowindow-contents-in-google-map-android-api-v2-using-infowindowadapter/)

Comment: For adding a marker on touch you can refer [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-marker-on-touched-location-of-google-maps-using-android-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/)

Comment: After do tons of research, here is what i am thinking: 1) get the Latlng from the map listener when you click the map. 2) Do the place search from web url [here](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search) and get the place_id. 3) pass the place_id by using `GeoDataApi.getPlaceById `to get `Place` object [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android/place-details), then you can get places details. 4) if you wanna show the details, set up a `infoWindow` for the map, and show the details as you wish.